# How on one click another page div value change using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two page page1.php, page2.php and one JS file Control.js.

In page1.php

HTML :

```
<img src="images/b.jpg" width="31" height="26" id="imgClick1" onClick="return changeImage1(this)" >
```

In Control.js

```
function changeImage1() {

document.getElementById("imgClick1").src = "images/b.jpg";
document.getElementById('num1').style.color = "#fff";
document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "Hello friend";
        }
```

In page2.php

```
<div id="text1">
Hello world
</div>
```

So using JavaScript I am trying to write "hello friend" in the div "text1" of page page2.php when I click the image or the div of page1.php.

1. Is there any possible way to use JS to solve this problem?
2. Can we use any how `document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML` or something like that in the program?

Comment: How are Page1 & Page2 linked? Seperate pages or they included in the same document?

Comment: yes, Page1 & Page2 are seperate. actually this two page are two iframe  in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you make use of the `include` function of php (provided you absolutely want to keep your `text1` div on a separate page), like this on your `page1.php` file:

```
include('page2.php');
```

Make sure that when you do that, `page1.php` and `page2.php` are in the same folder, otherwise you may define a path to it like this:

```
include('/path/to/page2.php');
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. actually I use the include option of php in my program but it not work well because it include all the picture of page1.php in the page2.php file that I don't want. Can you suggest some think else please.

Comment: easiest is if you simply take the stuff you need from `page2.php` and add it into `page1.php` without using `include`, or break up `page2.php` into multiple parts, depending on what you need from each, and only call one or the other with `include` if you need them...